# How do you batch resizes of Genesis videos in FFMPEG?

Tags: ffmpeg, encoding, codec, libx264, x264

I am trying to a create 4:3 video upscale encodes with Sega Genesis videos that are usually around 320 x 224 using FFMPEG. While I had been advised to use FFMPEG (and AVISynth) in the past, it was only until fairly recently that I started it to use it and I am still learning about FFMPEG. Prior to using FFMPEG, I mostly used a setup where I used Virtualdub2 to do two resize filters (Nearest Neighbor; Lanzcos3) while using "compute from height ratio" on the second resize filter. I had been looking for better methods to upscale my videos while still maintaining the quality of the videos. [Here are some of the methods](https://plutiedev.com/ffmpeg) [tried using the resources](http://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/H.264#LosslessH.264) I found on the internet:

ffmpeg i -s 1440x1080 -sws_flags neighbor -c:v libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p -c:a aac -b:a 256k

ffmpeg -i mysourcevideo.avi -vf scale=1600:1120 -sws_flags neighbor -c:v libx264 -crf 10 -c:a aac -q:a 2 outputfile.mp4

These methods appear to work but the thing is I am working with pixel art form older videos and I do not what methods work those kinds of systems. I also learned that while some older consoles can upscaled to 4:3, not all may look good for those for video streaming. I could be wrong or at least inaccurate but what FFMPEG settings that I can use to upscale Genesis (both emulated or otherwise) videos? I also want it pixel accurate with Nearest Neighbor/PointResize, YUV420, AAC with an MP4 container.

Comment: What have you looked into so far? Any searches you've done? Any things you've tried?

Comment: I looked to sites like TASvideos where they gave me a FFMPEG script for some good encodes.  I also looked to other video forum sites where I can find more tips on FFMPEG encoding. They seem to work but I am looking for somethign that can account for all Genesis video dumps.

Comment: You can edit your question to include things you've tried. "they seem to work but" : please write in your question what commands you've tried that seemed to work, but could not account for all genesis video dumps. No need to write "edit", "update", just update your question as if you're asking it for the first time, but with all the relevant details.

Comment: Okay I will do that.